# Error en programa C (no regisrtra la primera variable)

Tags: c

Que,tal. Tengo un programa donde se crean 4 registros con el nombre, apellido materno,paterno y fecha de nacimiento. Sin embargo al SEGMENTATION CORE DUMPED y se cierra. SOy nueva en C y no tengo ni idea de que es lo que puedo estar haciendo mal. `

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct registro{
    char nombre[50];
    char materno[50];
    char paterno[50];
    int mes;
    int year;
    int dia;
    int identificacion;
}registros[4];

int main(){
    int menu;
    int show=1;
    int count;
    int countyear=0;
    int countmonth=0;
    int countday=0;

    fflush(stdin);

    do{
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nBienvenido\n");
    printf("Ingrese una opcion:\n");
    printf("1.Registro y Consulta\n");
    printf("2.Salida\n");

    scanf("%d",&menu);
    if(menu==1){
        do{

        fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nRegistro");
    count ++;
        fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese su nombre:\n");
    fgets(registros[count].nombre,50,stdin);

    if(count==3){
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(registros[count].nombre,50,stdin);
    }

    if(count==4){
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(registros[count].nombre,50,stdin);
    }
    if (count==5){
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(registros[count].nombre,50,stdin);
    }
    printf("\nIngrese su apellido paterno:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(registros[count].paterno,50,stdin);
    printf("\nIngrese su apellido materno:\n");
    fgets(registros[count].materno,50,stdin);

    do{
        printf("\nIngrese su an]o de nacimiento:\n");
        scanf("%i",&countyear);
        if(countyear>=1900 && menu <=2018){
            if(countyear>=1900 && countyear <=2000){
                countyear=countyear-1900;
                    registros[count].year=countyear;
            }
        if(countyear>=2000 && countyear <=2100){
            countyear=countyear-2000;
            registros[count].year=countyear;
        }
        break;
        }

    }while(1);
    do{
         printf("\nIngrese su dia de nacimiento:\n");
         scanf("%i",&countday);
         if(countday>=1 && countday<=31){
            registros[count].dia=countday;
            break;
         }
    }while(1);

    do{
        printf("\nIngrese su mes de nacimiento:\n");
        scanf("%i",&countmonth);
        if(countmonth>=1 && countmonth <=12){
            registros[count].mes=countmonth;
            break;
        }
    }while(1);
    registros[count].identificacion=count;

}while(count<=4);

    printf("\nConsultas\n");
        do{
            show++;
            printf("\n%.2s",registros[show].nombre);
            printf("%.2s",registros[show].paterno);
            printf("%.2s",registros[show].materno);
            printf("%.2i",registros[show].dia);
                printf("%.2i",registros[show].mes);
                    printf("%.2i",registros[show].year);
                        printf("%.2i",registros[show].dia);
                        printf("%.i",registros[show].identificacion);
        }while(show<=4);

    }//FIN DE OPCION 1 REGISTRO

    if(menu==2){
        printf("Salida");

        /*do{
            show++;
            printf("\n%.2s",registros[show].nombre);
            printf("%.2s",registros[show].paterno);
            printf("%.2s",registros[show].materno);
            printf("%.2i",registros[show].dia);
                printf("%.2i",registros[show].mes);
                    printf("%.2i",registros[show].year);
                        printf("%.2i",registros[show].dia);
                        printf("%.i",registros[show].identificacion);
        }while(show<=4);*/

    }
    if(menu>2){
        printf("\nFavor de ingresar un numero valido\n");
    }

}while(menu !=2);

return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no inicializas `count` en ningún momento:

```
int count;

// ...

count++;

// ...

fgets(registros[count].nombre,50,stdin);
```

En consecuencia, esta variable tendrá un valor aleatorio dentro del rango de un `int` (32 bits de posibilidades!!!). Las probabilidades que mágicamente `count` valga 0, que es lo que a ti te interesa son mínimas.

Dado que no estamos en la edad de piedra y ni siquiera ya en el siglo pasado, en C **ya no es necesario** declarar todas las variables al inicio de la función. Suele ser más saludable reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible:

```
int count;
for(count=0; count<4; count++)
{
   printf("Ingrese su nombre:\n");
   fgets(registros[count].nombre,50,stdin);

   // ...
}
```

También te sugiero dividir el código en funciones y tabularlo correctamente... por eso de que sea más manejable y legible

> El problema es que no podemos usar FOR por instrucciones de la profesora.

Sustituir `for` por `while` es trivial:

```
int count = 0;
while(count<4)
{
  printf("Ingrese su nombre:\n");
  fgets(registros[count].nombre,50,stdin);

  // ...

  count++;
}
```

Comment: El problema es que no podemos usar FOR por instrucciones de la profesora.

Answer (score 0):

el lenguaje C no inicializa las variables, así que nunca esperes resultado claros si no esta asegurado el valor inicial. como "buenas practicas", en programación, se recomienda incializar las variables, aun cuando sea 0 (cero para variables numericas) o vacio (para char o arreglos char, comunmente denominado string), o al menos, en los años de ejercicio, lo he usado como un denominador para el desarrollo de mis aplicaciones.